# How to perform testing on an already installed android app using appium?

Tags: android, ruby, testing, webdriver, appium

I want to write webdriver testcase using appium, where the app must not be reinstalled for every run. How to launch the already installed app and perform testing?

Answer (score 0):

Once the app is installed it shouldn't need to reinstall when running the next test. Be sure to check your configs and are referencing the correct app, app-package, and app-activity.

Comment: It doesn't reinstall, but clears the application data on each scenario. How do I prevent that from happening. I am using ruby with appium.